# Use context processor only for specific application

Tags: django

I've been looking for some days now, if it's possible to set a context processor for a specific range of urls. But so far i haven't found anything.

I would like to calculate the count of objects in a list so in my template I could put

```
<ul>
<li><a href="{%url unread_mails %}">Unread mails (42)</a></li>
<li><a href="{%url deleted_mails %}">Deleted mails (5)</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, this would only be necessary for 5 views (could be more in the future) in the same application. Would it be possible to enable a context processor for just this app?

Comment: Why don't you use ajax to short poll and add this in an included template, so you only have to edit it in one place.

Comment: I could do that, but i was wondering if it would be possible by using context processors

Comment: You can't add a context processor for a specific range of urls. Every context processor would run for all requests.

Comment: Thanks both. I'll go for the AJAX approach then.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I want my context processor to run only when admin dashboard is hit otherwise not. So I have implemented something like

```
def custom_context_processor(request,*args,**kwargs):
if '/' in request.META['PATH_INFO']:
    return {"something"}
else:
    #do something
```

This one worked for me